# NgRX effect called with empty state

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

I am having some troubles with the state of a redux app. Let's say that a couple of actions update the state. When an NgRX effect is triggered then suddenly the state disappears and the next action that goes to the reducer takes the initialState.

Here is my effect:

```
@Effect() getConfiguration$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(PlasmaAction.PlasmaActionTypes.GET_CONFIGURATION),
    switchMap((action: PlasmaAction.PlasmaActions) => {
        return this.plasmaService.send(action.payload).pipe(
            map(result => {
            return new PlasmaAction.SetConfiguration(result);
            })
        );
    })
);
```

Up to dispatching the GET_CONFIGURATION action the state is fine, but then the state looks this way: 
[redux-dev-tools-screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZemM.png) and the state is empty. Am I missing something?

P.S. The SET_CONFIGURATION is dispatched and updates the state with the new configuration and all other attributes are back to the initial ones.

@EDIT: Here is my reducer. With a little bit of debugging from my side:

```
export function plasmaReducer(state: PlasmaState, action: PlasmaActions) {
if (!state) {
    console.log('%c STATE IS EMPTY', 'color:red;');
    state = initialState;
}
switch (action.type) {
    case PlasmaActionTypes.CONNECTION_OPENED: {

        return { ...state, connected: true };
    }
    case PlasmaActionTypes.CONNECTION_CLOSED: {
        return { ...state, connected: false };
    }
    case PlasmaActionTypes.SET_CONFIGURATION: {
        return { ...state, configuration: action.payload };
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Can you provide the reducer code? What is result?

Comment: Please check the edited post above.

Comment: When an action is caught by an effect,  the state changes its value to {}. The next action calls the reducer with an empty state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You reducer should **always** have a `default` case.

Every action is passed through every reducer loaded in your application. This means if you don't handle the "other" actions inside your reducer the reducer returns `undefined`, hence the empty state you see.

To handle the "other" actions, use a `default` case and simply return the state as is:

```
switch (action.type) {
    case PlasmaActionTypes.CONNECTION_OPENED: {

        return { ...state, connected: true };
    }
    case PlasmaActionTypes.CONNECTION_CLOSED: {
        return { ...state, connected: false };
    }
    case PlasmaActionTypes.SET_CONFIGURATION: {
        return { ...state, configuration: action.payload };
    }

    default:
         return state;
}
```

Comment: That's it! Silly mistake from my side. Thanks a lot!

Comment: This issue is so subtle it's almost impossible to figure out.